# Why my Spring Boot @Pointcut not triggering with @Around advise and ProceedingJoinPoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am trying to log some info during api call in console in my Spring Boot application. I have used Spring Aop and trying to use @Around advise with @Pointcut by using ProceedingJoinPoint. The program is compiling successfully & runs quite well. But logging is not happening in console. I think my Pointcut is not triggering. My code is given bellow. Please help.

```
package org.mycomp.mat.aspect;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.mycomp.mycompmat.user.profile.service.UserProfile;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.mycomp.mat.repository..*(..))")
    public void requestPointcut() {
    }

    @Around("requestPointcut()")
    public Object requestLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String methodName = proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        String className = proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().toString();
        Object[] inputArguments = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();

        logger.info(
                "Operation " + methodName +
                        " Of " + className +
                        " On " + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME) +
                        " With Input Parameters :-> " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputArguments)
        );

        Object object = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        logger.info(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));

        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without more iformation or ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I cannot do more than speculate. E.g., the target class might not be a Spring-managed bean, or you are trying to intercept a private methods, or the aspect is not picked up by component scan because it is in a package outside the main application package. Please improve the question.

Comment: Sir, the Target class is marked as @Repository, the methods are public & the package is inside the main application package.

Comment: No need to call me Sir, wie are all peers here.  I think the problem is in the code I cannot see. So please be advised to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and publish it on GitHub. Then I or someone else can take a closer look, reproducing your problem.

Answer (score -1):

the issue is with the pointcut expression missing * for the class name part
like org.mycomp.mat.repository.myClass.myMethod({arguments})

change from `@Pointcut("execution(public * org.mycomp.mat.repository..*(..))")` to `@Pointcut("execution(public * org.mycomp.mat.repository.*.*(..))")`

Comment: There is no missing `*`, the pointcut is correct and your suggestion is not proper Spring AOP or AspectJ syntax, even after your 3rd edit. Please, better don't reply if you are just guessing. The OP is looking for help, not for more confusion.

Comment: After your final edit (before you changed the answer several times while I was commenting), I can say that your suggestion makes the pointcut less versatile than before, because `repository..*` matches all methods in all classes in that package **including sub-packages**, while your version `repository.*.*` only matches methods in classes **directly** in the `repository` package. So your idea is nice, but it does not help and there is **no issue** with the OP's pointcut, like I said. The problem must be elsewhere. This answer is invalid, unfortunately.